# How to change the cursor line highlighting for one window in vim?

Tags: vim

How to change the cursor line highlighting for one window?
I namely want the quick fix with the `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

Patch 8.0.0641 introduced a separate highlight group for the quickfix line, called QuickFixLine. With patch 8.0.0653 this group is linked to the Search highlight by default, because for some color schemes the colors chosen for patch 8.0.0641 did not work well.

So if you have a current version of Vim you can use

```
 hi QuickFixLine cterm=None ctermbg=256 guibg=#ffff00
```

to make the current line in the quickfix window more distinguishable.

Comment: I did not find any difference in highlighting after using this command in my .vimrc file.  Actually, when using quickfix , the line when points to a error, the word error is not visible and is visible only when i move to the next error.

Comment: setlocal nocursorline
hi Search cterm=none ctermbg=226 guibg=#ffff00

Comment: I tested then posted... try to send screenshot of error

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mnbgy_EMR88mKG-qUAtPmLy_TwgDZo0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks. The changes are reflected in vim but for gvim, what should i do. Can there be other highlighting scheme that can provide adequate highlighting for both vim and gvim

Comment: i m not sure about that

Comment: QuickFixLine is not CursorLine. QuickFixLine refers to actually selected item while CursorLine defines the line the cursor is on. These two are two separated lines whenever the cursor is not on the currently selected QF item. QuickFixLine, when introduced, enabled to define separate colors for the current item but CursorLine, as far as I know, cannot be set separately for particular windows. That's what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

To set cursor line highlight in quickfix window:

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &ft=="qf" | setlocal cul | endif
```

Comment: This will affect all windows. The question was about changing highlighting in one of them only.

Comment: This answer is the correct one now. The other answer here is about QuickFixLine what is something completely different. Anyway, I am still missing one thing - the possibility to set different colors for the CursorLine in a standard and QuickFix windows. I think that it could not be done. I can change the colors on active window switch but both windows will be always affected by the change.